Powershell Script to Convert Mulitple Excel worksheets from the same workbook into individual PDFs, being name after the worksheet title
Powershell Script to Convert Mulitple Excel worksheets from the same workbook into individual PDFs, being name after the worksheet title.
$path = “I:\”
$xlFixedFormat = “Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.xlFixedFormatType” -as [type]
$excelFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -include *.xls, *.xlsx -recurse
$objExcel = New-Object -ComObject excel.application
$objExcel.visible = $false
foreach($wb in $excelFiles)
 {
$filepath = Join-Path -Path $path -ChildPath ($wb.BaseName + “.pdf”)
$workbook = $objExcel.workbooks.open($wb.fullname, 3)
$workbook.Saved = $true
“saving $filepath”
$workbook.ExportAsFixedFormat($xlFixedFormat::xlTypePDF, $filepath)
$objExcel.Workbooks.close()
 }
$objExcel.Quit()`


Unsure on powershell but if you're open to a vba solution this is very doable.

I'd recommend taking a look to the great module from Doug Finke ImportExcel. That could make this task much easier.

What is your question?

@Robert I was wanting to Convert Multiple Excel worksheets from the same workbook into individual PDFs, each being name after the worksheet title. I couldn't get them to be named properly or be pulled individually. However I did end up solving the issue

I was able to find the solution. This also saves the PDFs with their specific worksheet name.
$path = “C:\Testing”
$xlFixedFormat = “Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.xlFixedFormatType” -as 
[type]
$excelFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Testing\file.xlsx"
$objExcel = New-Object -ComObject excel.application
$objExcel.visible = $false
foreach($wb in $excelFiles)
{
 $workbook = $objExcel.workbooks.open($wb.fullname, 3)
foreach ($sheet in $workbook.Worksheets) {
 $filepath = Join-Path -Path $path -ChildPath ($sheet.BaseName)
 $sheet.ExportAsFixedFormat($xlFixedFormat::xlTypePDF, $filepath + 
 $sheet.Name)}
 $workbook.Saved = $true
“saving $filepath”
 $objExcel.Workbooks.close()
}
$objExcel.Quit()

